# How to bind a ContentView to a property?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I'm having a hard time binding a ContentView to a property in a C# Xamarin app.

Here is how I'm composing it:

```
protected override View MyView
{
    get
    {
        if (_myView == null)
        {
            _myView = new ContentView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 40),
                Content = new StackLayout(),
            };

            if (Vm.ItemCount > 0)
            {
                (_myView.Content as StackLayout).Children.Add(MyListview);
            }
            else
            {
                (_myView.Content as StackLayout).Children.Add(NothingExistsLabel);
            }
        }

        return _myView;
    }
}
```

Now Vm.ItemCount can change any time, but the UI does not get updated.

Is there a way I can databind the ContentView to the Vm.ItemCount, such that the UI would update itself automatically whenever the ItemCount changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Content is not a bindable property.  You could wire up a method to the ItemCount setter to refresh your UI whenever ItemCount was updated.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Thanks for the advice. Whenever you get a chance, could you post that as an answer for me to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is not a bindable property.

You could wire up a method to the ItemCount setter to refresh your UI whenever ItemCount was updated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a view by yourself, the Xamarin engine can't know the property is changed unless you notify that a change occurs.

You have 2 solutions:

- Implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged on your view, so that Xamarin could bind to your event "PropertyChanged"
- (Sincertly my favorite) Use MVVM Helpers nuget https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers which simplify the implementation. ex:

Your Model

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel // From MVVM Helpers nuget
{
    private IEnumerable<int> count;
    public IEnumerable<int> Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { SetProperty(ref count, value); }
    }
}
```

Your View

```
public class MyView : ContentView
{
    private MyViewModel Vm { get; set; }

    public MyView()
    {
        this.Vm = new MyViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = this.Vm;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.Vm.Count = 42;
    }
}
```

Add Binding in your Xaml

```
<Label Text = "{Binding Count}" />
```